# How to send mails with dynamic distribution list

Tags: excel, vba, macos, email

I am trying to send mail to a number of email ids every week. Email id count  changes every week (dynamic data set).

Each mail needs to go to three different recipients as per below table.
[image]

I tried a macro for last row count. If mails need to send to 30 email ids then only going to first 29 email ids.

```vb
Sub (mail)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim mailid1, mailid2, mailid3 As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Counter = Rng.Count

    For i = 2 To Counter ' due to headers i taken as 2 

        mailid1= Cells(i, 1).Value
        mailid2= Cells(i, 2).Value
        mailid3= Cells(i, 3).Value
      
        With outmail

            outmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "abx@abc.com"
            .To = mailid1 & ";" & mailid2
            .CC = mailid3
            .Importance = 2

            .Subject = mail subject

            .HTMLBody = Mail text
        
            .Attachments.Add ("File1")
            .Attachments.Add ("File2")
        
            .send
                    
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Increment i for looping, wait at least 10 seconds before sending next email
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Next i

    Loop

    MsgBox "Email Sucessfull for ALL"
     
End Sub
```

Comment: That `Loop` doesn't have a `Do` that opens it and the subroutine name shouldn't be in brackets. Anyway, assuming that the mail-specific code is working (and i don't think that `mail subject` and `Mail text` would make it possible), i'd suggest to check your data because the code should cover the whole list. Are all the e-mail address valid?

Comment: thanks by mistake I mentioned loop here.. i have just given sample mail ids to make you understand the requirement. thanks it's sorted out now..I got answer my self..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer the answer by myself. i have made below changes..

```
  Set rng = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
 Counter = rng.Count
  For i = 2 To Counter
```

and add one more coding

```
  If RequestorEmail <> blank Then 'header name of Row B
        
  With outmail
```